# How to change from address in workflow email?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

sharepoint workflow (created using SharePoint designer and the workflow is in 2010)  at the movement sent emails using default email address of the sharepoint in our case it is companyname@mydomain.com can you change this?

Comment: Please refer this link - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2014/10/24/you-cant-specify-the-from-address-for-email-messages-when-you-use-the-send-an-email-option-from-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-action/

Comment: my workflow is in 2010 sorry i haven't mentioned that before i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

By default you could not change "From" address in SPD workflow.

You should use custom or third-party send email activity.

The project from CodePlex will allow you to specify the sender in the workflow, refer to the following URL

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/